# Use a dataframe and assign a pattern with Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I would to someone help me with the follow:

I would like tyo use spacy for identify a pattern in a dataframe

This is the dataframe:
Input

```
Import pandas as pd
testNet=pd.DataFrame([[12,"Excellent but I want to buy it"],
                      [18,"Super I wish to buy it"],
                      [23,"We hope to buy now"],
                      [24,"She hope to buy now and I want to buy now"],
                     ],columns=["ID","CONTENT"])
```

The pattern is the follow:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

from spacy.matcher import Matcher

doc1=nlp("Excellent but I want to buy it")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)


pattern = [{"POS": "PRON"},{"POS": "VERB"},{"TEXT": "to", "OP": "?"}, {"LEMMA": "buy"}]

# Add the pattern to the matcher and apply the matcher to the doc
matcher.add("BUY_PATTERN", None, pattern)
matches = matcher(doc1)

print("Total matches found:", len(matches))

# Iterate over the matches and print the span text
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print("Match found:", doc1[start:end].text)
```

The problem is that I can not get to use the dataframe in the pattern I only can enter the information row by row and I would like to enter the dataframe. Because the dataframe original has 300.000 rows.

The output that I wish to get would be the follow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HODZL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a function say `get_matches()` that takes in the text as input and returns the "matches" and then apply lambda function to the dataframe as follows:

```
testNet['MATCH'] = testNet.CONTENT.apply(lambda x : get_matches(x))
```